# Rails 3 - Retrieving Data from HABTM relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following tables - groups, contacts, contacts_groups (habtm join table)

groups & contacts are owned by a user and both have user_id columns

Question:

When I am in the groups controller and I want to access all the contacts that belong to that group how do I do this?

url looks like

http://localhost:3000/users/2/groups/5

my view looks like this

```
<p>
  <b>Name:</b>
  <%= @group.name %>
</p>

<p>Associated Contacts</p>


<% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= contact.firstname %></td>

<% end %>
```

in my Groups controller i have

```
  def show
    @contacts = Contact.accessible_by(current_ability)
  end
```

This returns ALL contacts the current user has access to. How can I return the contacts that belong to the group i am currently viewing?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try this:

```
@group.contacts
```

So the view would be:

```
<p>
  <b>Name:</b>
  <%= @group.name %>
</p>

<p>Associated Contacts</p>


<% @group.contacts.each do |contact| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= contact.firstname %></td>

<% end %>
```